# Matlab: Using webread/webwrite to access website that is protected by ddos service

Tags: matlab, web, https

I am trying to let Matlab automatically screen for new coin removal posts on a specific website: https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us (or more specifically: https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/sections/200560334-Coin-Removals). However, whenever I use the respective matlab functions urlread or webread. This is the code I use to retrieve the data:

```
url = 'https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/sections/200560334-Coin-Removals';
data = webwrite(url);
```

When I execute this code, the following error is returned:

```
Error using readContentFromWebService (line 45)
The server returned the status 503 with message "Service Temporarily Unavailable" in response to the request to URL
https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/sections/200560334-Coin-Removals.
Error in webread (line 122)
[varargout{1:nargout}] = readContentFromWebService(connection, options);
```

When I access the webpage with my browser, sometimes a pre-loading page appears where it says "checking your browser ..." or something like that which I believe is related to some sort of DDoS protection deployed by the host of the website. After a few seconds, you then have access to the actual website. The following works just fine:

```
url = 'https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/sections/200560334-Coin-Removals';
web(url);
```

The matlab browser openes the website as you would expect. Does anyone have an idea on how to retrieve the data from this website like webread would usually do (hence the simply html-text)?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that DDoS protection only trigger if you are, well, spamming as a DDos-er. Make sure your code has a reasonable query delay, if you are trying to read every millisecond, makes sense that the webpage stops you. I also assume that the message "wait a second until we redirect you" that appears in the webpage is designed specifically so you don't programatically get to their webpage? Just assumptions, I know little about this stuff

Comment: yes that would make sense - but I am not spamming at all. Just executing the code once delivers the error mentioned above. I am also not planning to execute the request multiple times per second - rather once every hour or so